# display three random articles in a partial view mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, random

I have a blog in which one of the pages is MainDetails, here I display the current blog, inside this details page I display a `partialview` and in that partial I am trying to display three `random` similar posts. However I am abit stuck with the syntax:

In my partial view all I am doing is displaying the posts in my list, however I want to display only 3 posts related to the Category property, but at `random`. `Post` has the property `CategoryId`, `Post` has a many to one relationship with Category (category can have many posts but post can only have one category), I am trying to get 3 randoms posts related by category:

**PostController** **GetSimilarPosts** Action:

```
    public ActionResult GetSimilarPosts(int id = 0)
    {
        var randomPosts = db.Categories.Where(p => p.Id == id).SelectMany(p => p.Posts).OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(3);
        return View(randomPosts.ToList());
    }
```

However the output on my `maindetails` page for the above action and `partialview` is still showing more than 3 items:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean you are a bit stuck with the syntax? Could you please give a proper description of the problem?

Comment: Your controller should be determining the 3 random articles.  Your view should only be looping through and displaying them (no logic!!!).

Comment: Its just for simplicity.

Comment: @GarrithGraham Your view should not contain any logic. It is not simpler to place logic into your views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to have 3 random articles you could use something like this

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
     private DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();

     public ActionResult RandomPosts(int categoryId)
     {
          var randomPosts = db.Posts.Where(x => x.CategoryId == categoryId)
                                    .OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(3);
          return View(randomPosts);
     }
}
```

And inside your view you would call it with the following

```
@Html.Action("RandomPosts", "Home", new { categoryId = 1 })
```

Comment: Hi see my update, I was updating my question before your edit.

Comment: Your method and mine still return the full list

Comment: Its because you use Html.Partial instead of Html.Action. Html.Partial just renders the view with parameter as model instead of calling the action. You need to use Html.Action("GetSimilarPosts", new { id = 1 }) inside your view.

Comment: Add into begin of your RandomPosts view the next line
@{
    Layout = null;
}