# @Html.Action is mirrioring my website from a partial view with no reference to the layout page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a `PartialView` called `GetSimilarPosts` in my `Post` Views folder and in my main details page I have this link:

```
@Html.Action("GetSimilarPosts", "Post", new { id = Model.CurrentPost.Category.Id })
```

This is the Partial View:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyBlogger.Models.Post>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <p class="text-left">Similar Article: <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Post", new { urlslug = item.UrlSlug })">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</a></p>
}
```

But something strange is happening... the partial view does not reference my layout page but somehow its duplicating my entire page when I load maindetails:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your controller, are you returning using `View` or `PartialView`

View will render with the Master Page, PartialView will render just the view

```
public ActionResult GetSimilarPosts(int id) {
   var model = _repository.GetSimilarPosts(id); // data retrieval

   return PartialView("_viewName", model);
}
```

Comment: Although it should be kept in mind that it adds an overhead of going back to call an action

Comment: this trips me up many times when I jump into a new project. I render partial views quite often with jquery and end up with the same issue you had.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're using the incorrect method... instead of `@Html.Action` use `@Html.Partial`.

`@Html.Action()` will execute an Action on your Controller, and then return the result, Html.Partial won't execute any actions, instead returning only the PartialView specified.

Comment: Hmm see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29900080/display-three-random-articles-in-a-partial-view-mvc